# How to make field variable of java filter not shared across all the sessions?

Tags: java, spring, session, jakarta-ee, session-variables

Please suggest me some solution immediately,

```
public class SessionTImeOutFilter implements Filter {
    String check = "";
```

The about check is my field variable. When I deploy the application in tomcat and if multiple users are accessing the application, The variable **check** is getting shared by all the sessions of users.

Kindly, Suggest me some way to keep the variable **check** not shared among all sessions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong Design, It ll be shared for all the requests. As only one instance of filter will be created per jvm. What do you want to do with check btw

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep the `String check = ""` inside the `doFilter` method like this

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain){  
    String check = ""; 
    //all other stuff
}
```

Comment: But I want to keep the **check** variable value remain same for one session.... If I initialize in doFilter , It would be re-initialized for every request.

Comment: can any request change the value of check ?

Comment: Yes the requests of same session, But not the requests of some other session..............

Answer (score 0):

Save it *in* the session, as an attribute. If not there, create it the first time. Don't make it an instance member of the filter.

Comment: Tried that one too...... If session has timedout, I would not be in a position to get that value.... Here my objective is to find out session timeout in my algorithm..................

Comment: If the session has timed out there is no session to timeout, so why do you care? You need to decide here. If it's a non-shared session attribute, it goes in the session. That's what you asked for.